# Curl ou WebService Executando JavaScript

Tags: php, java, libcurl

Estou com um problema crônico, preciso que uma requisição CURL execute códigos também em JavaScript.

De forma genérica, todos os posts e referências apontam para a mesma resposta, que o curl não tem capacidade de executar códigos em JavaScript, no entanto já encontrei API's em Java que Executavam a função CURL prometendo rodar códigos em JavaScripts (como a HTML Unit, por exemplo), no entanto observei que estas API's foram abandonadas pelos desenvolvedores.

Eu precisaria algo neste sentido, pois preciso interagir que sites que fazem requisições via JavaScript.

Não adianta ver a requisição pelo navegador e colocá-la no curl, esse código em JavaScript visa justamente impedir a interação por webServices, criando chaves em JavaScript que são enviados ao servidor para liberar a próxima requisição.

Em resumo, preciso de alguma API, código, Facilidade ou tecnologia que possa simular um navegador possibilitando as requisições Curl mas rodando os códigos JavaScripts como é a promessa desta api HTMLUnit.

O ideal seria em linguagem PHP, mas acredito que não exista, na falta o JAVA resolve.

Alguém poderia por favor me auxiliar neste problema?

Comment: Deixa eu entender. Você quer que o CURL chame o servidor que vai te devolver algum conteúdo. Não entendi quando o Javascript deve rodar o porquê disso. Esse javascript já vai estar no servidor ou será enviado pelo CURL? O que exatamente o javascript fará e o que exatamente o servidor deve retornar?

Comment: Muitos sites colocam códigos em javascript para impedir que robôs acessem os dados ou efetuem determinados posts. Por exemplo, mandando como um dado hiddem em um formulário web um código gerado dinamicamente no navegador, é uma forma de ter certeza que é um usuário acessando. Se o CURL pudesse rodar javascript ele geraria este código e voltaria este dado post como um perfeito navegador. Não adianta estudar o código gerado, o algoritimo, além de complexo, muda todo o tempo fazendo com que o site não possa ser acessado via curl, como os sites judiciais por exemplo ou mesmo o google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma maneira legal de emular navegadores é via [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) usando Java, C#, Ruby, Python ou Javascript com NodeJS. Através dele é possível realizar operações em um navegador web emulado.

Normalmente é utilizado para testes, mas pode atender o seu caso. Mas então sua aplicação não seria diferente de um robô e poderia ser utilizado para fins benéficos ou não.

Comment: Sim, pelo visto ele emula um navegador como todas as funções (possivelmente rodará o Java Script), é possível efetuar troca de dados através de seus comandos? da mesma maneira que fazemos no CURL? pois meu objetivo é capturar e trocar informações com os sites interagindo com meu sistema (é escrito em PHP, mas posso fazer rodar um java em segundo plano salvando no BD), isso é possível? se você já trabalhou com ele, há algum código de exemplos para eu ter ideia? Desde já obrigado, não sabe o quanto é difícil encontrar essa resposta.

Comment: É meu amigo, olhando por alto aqui sim, parece possível que esta API resolva meu problema, estarei agora nestas férias trabalhando com elas para tentar aprender a usá-la.